# Creating a Powershell Script to get disk info of remote machines

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have been playing with a script i found online that gives you a breakdown of your disks and a lovely pie chart after.

I was wondering this; we currently have VPN running to all our customer sites where there the servers are.

I can get to them all using the local IP for administration purposes via RDCM or Web Browser. I was wondering if there is anyway for me to be able to run the shell command directly from my machine and listing the ip's of the machines i want checked.

I tried using a list file of the ip's but it just returns nothing.

It would save a lot of time rather than clicking through all 100 servers to get the info every month.

Things to bare in mind:

Each site has it's own domain and admin account/password to access.

Here is the script which is direct from the technet script centre (I havent placed any details in.) It works fine when i run it directly on the machine):

```
        #### Spreadsheet Location
 $DirectoryToSaveTo = "c:\"
 $date=Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d"
 $Filename="serverinfo-$($date)"
 $FromEmail="<ToEmail>"
 $ToEmail="<FromEmail>"
 $SMTPMail="<SMTP MAIL>"

 ###InputLocation
 $Computers = Get-Content "c:\server.txt"


# before we do anything else, are we likely to be able to save the file?
# if the directory doesn't exist, then create it
if (!(Test-Path -path "$DirectoryToSaveTo")) #create it if not existing
  {
  New-Item "$DirectoryToSaveTo" -type directory | out-null
  }



#Create a new Excel object using COM 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $True
$Excel = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Sheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1)

$sheet.Name = 'Server Inventory'
#Create a Title for the first worksheet
$row = 1
$Column = 1
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'Server Inventory'

$range = $Sheet.Range("a1","s2")
$range.Merge() | Out-Null
$range.VerticalAlignment = -4160

#Give it a nice Style so it stands out
$range.Style = 'Title'

#Increment row for next set of data
$row++;$row++

#Save the initial row so it can be used later to create a border
#Counter variable for rows
$intRow = $row
$xlOpenXMLWorkbook=[int]51

#Read thru the contents of the SQL_Servers.txt file

$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1)  ="Name"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2)  ="status"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3)  ="OS"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4)  ="Domain Role"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5)  ="ProcessorName"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6)  ="Manufacturer"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,7)  ="Model"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,8)  ="SystemType"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,9)  ="Last Boot Time"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,10) ="Bios Version"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,11) ="CPU Info"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,12) ="NoOfProcessors"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,13) ="Total Physical Memory"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,14) ="Total Free Physical Memory"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,15) ="Total Virtual Memory"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,16) ="Total Free Virtual Memory"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,17) ="Disk Info"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,18) ="FQDN"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,19) ="IPAddress"

for ($col = 1; $col –le 19; $col++)
     {
          $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,$col).Font.Bold = $True
          $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,$col).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
          $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,$col).Font.ColorIndex = 34
     }

$intRow++


Function GetStatusCode
{ 
    Param([int] $StatusCode)  
    switch($StatusCode)
    {
        0       {"Success"}
        11001   {"Buffer Too Small"}
        11002   {"Destination Net Unreachable"}
        11003   {"Destination Host Unreachable"}
        11004   {"Destination Protocol Unreachable"}
        11005   {"Destination Port Unreachable"}
        11006   {"No Resources"}
        11007   {"Bad Option"}
        11008   {"Hardware Error"}
        11009   {"Packet Too Big"}
        11010   {"Request Timed Out"}
        11011   {"Bad Request"}
        11012   {"Bad Route"}
        11013   {"TimeToLive Expired Transit"}
        11014   {"TimeToLive Expired Reassembly"}
        11015   {"Parameter Problem"}
        11016   {"Source Quench"}
        11017   {"Option Too Big"}
        11018   {"Bad Destination"}
        11032   {"Negotiating IPSEC"}
        11050   {"General Failure"}
        default {"Failed"}
    }
}


Function GetUpTime
{
    param([string] $LastBootTime)
    $Uptime = (Get-Date) - [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($LastBootTime)
    "Days: $($Uptime.Days); Hours: $($Uptime.Hours); Minutes: $($Uptime.Minutes); Seconds: $($Uptime.Seconds)" 
}






foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
 {

 TRY {
 $OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer
 $Bios = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $Computer
 $sheetS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer
 $sheetPU = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor -ComputerName $Computer
 $drives = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3}
 $pingStatus = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from win32_PingStatus where Address='$Computer'"
 $IPAddress=(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}).ipaddress
 $FQDN=[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().Name
 $OSRunning = $OS.caption + " " + $OS.OSArchitecture + " SP " + $OS.ServicePackMajorVersion
 $NoOfProcessors=$sheetS.numberofProcessors
 $name=$SheetPU|select name -First 1
 $Manufacturer=$sheetS.Manufacturer
 $Model=$sheetS.Model
 $systemType=$sheetS.SystemType
 $ProcessorName=$SheetPU|select name -First 1
 $DomainRole = $sheetS.DomainRole
 $TotalAvailMemory = $OS.totalvisiblememorysize/1kb
 $TotalVirtualMemory = $OS.totalvirtualmemorysize/1kb
 $TotalFreeMemory = $OS.FreePhysicalMemory/1kb
 $TotalFreeVirtualMemory = $OS.FreeVirtualMemory/1kb
 $TotalMem = "{0:N2}" -f $TotalAvailMemory
 $TotalVirt = "{0:N2}" -f $TotalVirtualMemory
 $FreeMem = "{0:N2}" -f $TotalFreeMemory
 $FreeVirtMem = "{0:N2}" -f $TotalFreeVirtualMemory
 $date = Get-Date
 $uptime = $OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.lastbootuptime)
 $BiosVersion = $Bios.Manufacturer + " " + $Bios.SMBIOSBIOSVERSION + " " + $Bios.ConvertToDateTime($Bios.Releasedate)
 $sheetPUInfo = $name.Name + " & has " + $sheetPU.NumberOfCores + " Cores & the FSB is " + $sheetPU.ExtClock + " Mhz"
 $sheetPULOAD = $sheetPU.LoadPercentage

 if($pingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0)
    {
        $Status = GetStatusCode( $pingStatus.StatusCode )
    }
else
    {
    $Status = GetStatusCode( $pingStatus.StatusCode )
    }


 if (($DomainRole -eq "0") -or ($DomainRole -eq "1"))
 {
 $Role = "Work Station"
 }
 elseif (($DomainRole -eq "2") -or ($DomainRole -eq "3"))
 {
 $Role = "Member Server"
 }
 elseif (($DomainRole -eq "4") -or ($DomainRole -eq "5"))
 {
 $Role = "Domain Controller"
 }
 else
 {
 $Role = "Unknown"
 }
 }
 CATCH
 {
 $pcnotfound = "true"
 }
 #### Pump Data to Excel
 if ($pcnotfound -eq "true")
 {
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = "PC Not Found"
 }
 else
 {
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $computer
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $status
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 3) = $OSRunning
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 4) = $Role
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 5) = $name.name
 $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 6) = $Manufacturer
 $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 7) = $Model
 $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 8) = $SystemType
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 9) = $uptime
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 10)= $BiosVersion
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 11)= $sheetPUInfo
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 12)=$NoOfProcessors
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 13)= "$TotalMem MB"
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 14)= "$FreeMem MB"
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 15)= "$TotalVirt MB"
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 16)= "$FreeVirtMem MB"
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 19)=$IPAddress
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 18)=$FQDN


$driveStr = ""
 foreach($drive in $drives)
 {
 $size1 = $drive.size / 1GB
 $size = "{0:N2}" -f $size1
 $free1 = $drive.freespace / 1GB
 $free = "{0:N2}" -f $free1
 $freea = $free1 / $size1 * 100
 $freeb = "{0:N2}" -f $freea
 $ID = $drive.DeviceID
 $driveStr += "$ID = Total Space: $size GB / Free Space: $free GB / Free (Percent): $freeb % ` "
 }
 $sheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 17) = $driveStr
 }


$intRow = $intRow + 1
 $pcnotfound = "false"
 }

$erroractionpreference = “SilentlyContinue” 

$Sheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
########################################333

$Sheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(2)
$sheet.Name = 'DiskSpace'
$Sheet.Activate() | Out-Null

#Create a Title for the first worksheet
$row = 1
$Column = 1
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'Disk Space Information'

$range = $Sheet.Range("a1","h2")
$range.Merge() | Out-Null
$range.VerticalAlignment = -4160

#Give it a nice Style so it stands out
$range.Style = 'Title'

#Increment row for next set of data
$row++;$row++

#Save the initial row so it can be used later to create a border
$initalRow = $row

#Create a header for Disk Space Report; set each cell to Bold and add a background color
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'Computername'
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
$Column++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'DeviceID'
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
$Column++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'VolumeName'
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
$Column++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'TotalSizeGB'
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
$Column++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'UsedSpaceGB'
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
$Column++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'FreeSpaceGB'
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
$Column++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= '%Free'
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
$Column++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'State'
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True

#Set up a header filter
$headerRange = $Sheet.Range("a3","h3")
$headerRange.AutoFilter() | Out-Null

#Increment Row and reset Column back to first column
$row++
$Column = 1
$critical=0
$warning=0
$good=0

#Get the drives and filter out CD/DVD drives
foreach ($computer in $Computers)
 {
$diskDrives = Get-WmiObject win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType='3'" -ComputerName $computer

#Process each disk in the collection and write to spreadsheet
ForEach ($disk in $diskDrives) {
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,1)= $disk.__Server
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,2)= $disk.DeviceID
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,3)= $disk.VolumeName
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,4)= [math]::Round(($disk.Size /1GB),2)
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,5)= [math]::Round((($disk.Size - $disk.FreeSpace)/1GB),2)
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,6)= [math]::Round(($disk.FreeSpace / 1GB),2)
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,7)= ("{0:P}" -f ($disk.FreeSpace / $disk.Size))  

    #Determine if disk needs to be flagged for warning or critical alert
    If ($disk.FreeSpace -lt 5GB -AND ("{0:P}" -f ($disk.FreeSpace / $disk.Size))  -lt 40) {
        $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,8) = "Critical"
        $critical++
        #Check to see if space is near empty and use appropriate background colors
        $range = $Sheet.Range(("A{0}"  -f $row),("H{0}"  -f $row))
        $range.Select() | Out-Null    
        #Critical threshold         
        $range.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    } ElseIf ($disk.FreeSpace -lt 10GB -AND ("{0:P}" -f ($disk.FreeSpace / $disk.Size)) -lt 60) {
        $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,8) = "Warning"
        $range = $Sheet.Range(("A{0}"  -f $row),("H{0}"  -f $row))
        $range.Select() | Out-Null        
        $warning++
        $range.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    } Else {
        $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,8) = "Good"
        $good++
    }

     $row++
}
}

#Add a border for data cells
$row--
$dataRange = $Sheet.Range(("A{0}"  -f $initalRow),("H{0}"  -f $row))
7..12 | ForEach {
    $dataRange.Borders.Item($_).LineStyle = 1
    $dataRange.Borders.Item($_).Weight = 2
}

#Auto fit everything so it looks better

$usedRange = $Sheet.UsedRange                                                           
$usedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

$critical
$warning
$good

$sheet = $excel.Worksheets.Item(2) 

$row++;$row++

$beginChartRow = $Row

$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$Column) = 'Critical'
$Column++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$Column) = 'Warning'
$Column++
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$Column) = 'Good'
$Column = 1
$row++
#Critical formula
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$Column)=$critical
$Column++
#Warning formula
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$Column)=$warning
$Column++
#Good formula
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$Column)= $good

$endChartRow = $row

$chartRange = $Sheet.Range(("A{0}" -f $beginChartRow),("C{0}" -f $endChartRow))

##Add a chart to the workbook
#Open a sheet for charts
$temp = $sheet.Charts.Add()
$temp.Delete()
$chart = $sheet.Shapes.AddChart().Chart
$sheet.Activate()

#Configure the chart
##Use a 3D Pie Chart
$chart.ChartType = 70
$chart.Elevation = 40
#Give it some color
$sheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = .34
$sheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = 5
$sheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Fill.BackColor.TintAndShade = .765
$sheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = 5

$sheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Fill.TwoColorGradient(1,1)

#Set the location of the chart
$sheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Placement = 3
$sheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Top = 30
$sheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Left = 600

$chart.SetSourceData($chartRange)
$chart.HasTitle = $True

$chart.ApplyLayout(6,69)
$chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Disk Space Report"
$chart.ChartStyle = 26
$chart.PlotVisibleOnly = $False
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels().ShowValue = $True
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels().Separator = ("{0}" -f [char]10)

$chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels().Position = 2
#Critical
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 255
#Warning
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 65535
#Good
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 5287936

#Hide the data
$chartRange.EntireRow.Hidden = $True

$sheet.Name = 'DiskInformation'




$filename = "$DirectoryToSaveTo$filename.xlsx"
if (test-path $filename ) { rm $filename } #delete the file if it already exists
$Sheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
$Excel.SaveAs($filename, $xlOpenXMLWorkbook) #save as an XML Workbook (xslx)
$Excel.Saved = $True
$Excel.Close()
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$Excel.quit()


Function sendEmail([string]$emailFrom, [string]$emailTo, [string]$subject,[string]$body,[string]$smtpServer,[string]$filePath)
{
#initate message
$email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$email.From = $emailFrom
$email.To.Add($emailTo)
$email.Subject = $subject
$email.Body = $body
# initiate email attachment 
$emailAttach = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment $filePath
$email.Attachments.Add($emailAttach) 
#initiate sending email 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($email)
}

#Call Function 

#sendEmail -emailFrom pjayaram@appvion.com -emailTo 'pjayaram@appvion.com,pthangaraj@appvion.com,rmurugesan@appvion.com' -subject "INVENTORY" -body "Windows Server Inventory - COMPLETE DETAILS" -smtpServer hqmail01.appletonpapers.com -filePath $filename

$message = @" 
Hi Team,

The Discovery of Windows Server and Disk Space information for all the listed instances.

Autogenerated Email!!! Please do not reply.

Thank you, 
Appvion.com

"@        
$date=get-date

sendEmail -emailFrom $fromEmail -emailTo $ToEmail -subject "Windows Server Inventory & Disk Details -$($date)" -body $message -smtpServer $SMTPMail -filePath $filename
```

Many thanks to you all in advance.

Comment: Hi, does it work if you run it from a computer to a remote server in the same domain ?

Comment: Yes if i use the list text for the IP range within the same domain as ours it works fine. Problem is I am reaching out to over a 100 servers on many different domains.

Comment: Did you try to make a single WMI call to a server in an external domain to check if it worked ?

Comment: Like `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "AnExternalServer" -Credential (Get-Credential)`

Comment: OK but where in the code would I place that? Thanks!

Comment: Just run this command in a PS console or in a new ISE tab/file, to know if you can successfully retrieve WMI information from an external server. If it fails, your script will not run since it is mainly based on WMI.

Comment: That worked great. I was able to connect to the server. How would I implement that into the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each computer in an external domain, you will have to get the corresponding credentials at the beginning with, for example :

```
$storedCredential = Get-Credential
```

Then, when making WMI calls, you will need to specify these credentials, with for example :

```
$OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $storedCredential
$Bios = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $storedCredential
$sheetS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $storedCredential
```

Comment: This kind stranger is great thank you! I think i actually air punched. Only question is how do I get the info from the script that doesn't use the Get -WmiObject. Thanks again!

Comment: Dont worry I figured it out. I cant thank you enough for all your help. Script works a treat now! Saving myself hours of clicking.